# I need help Package Price in OpenCart

Tags: opencart, package

My Problem is the price product is 5€, and the Price Package is 120€

But in the Total Price is 125€, so, is adding the Price Package and the Price Product and I don't want this, I only want the Package Price, if the Price Product is 0, no problem, but another option?

Comment: Wait....Can you explain in more detail?
First : What are you trying to do.
Second:Do you offer shipping or is it free shipping
Third:Package how do you offer that? as in option or a must?

Comment: When adding to cart the product, which only allows buying package, the page where this package is offered, the price of individual product and package price shown, so when I add it to the cart, I sum the package price and the price of the product.
If the price of the product worth 5 € and the package price worth € 120, when I add it to the cart, shown € 125, the issue of expenses and fees manages shipments later and is controlled.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply,can you show me your site i want to see this in real time i can't imagine it otherwise